# Exoplayer Offline Playback with DRM

Tags: exoplayer2.x, drm

I am trying to implement an offline playback app using Exoplayer. I followed the demo code to implement download. It worked. But demo ise with latest Exoplayer version and in my case I can not upgrade exoplayer version due to some other unmanaged dependencies.

I am at 2.11.4 version. I have video files downloaded, I have the DRM keys downloaded with keySetId persisted. But I don't know how to use this keysetId to create a mediaSource and play the video.

Comment: Hi Olgun Kaya, I'm also encountering the same issue. Can you please share with me how you managed to solve this? Thanks :)

Comment: @MaRaM unfortunately I can not share too much since it is a commercial app. Please start a new thread and write down your pain points. I can then try to give some hints about them. for me, I took the main structure from demo app. But had to use old APIs to meet the same behavior.